# ArgumentNullException in JavaScript in a ASC.Net overextended control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

this bug has been a while (>2 years) in the application but wasn't noticed upon until lately (3 days ago). The control/code which contains the bug is a base class used by at least 50 other controls to extend from. The bug itself doesn't happen consistently but can be reproduced.

So the code in which it happens:

```
function AssertValidSelection<%=ClientID %>()
{
    var selection = selectedId<%=ClientID %>;
    console.log('AssertValidSelection()', selection);
    if (selection == null) {
        DisableButtons<%=this.ClientID %>();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The break occurs at 'DisableButtons<%=this.ClientID %>(); This function is created earlier in the code:

```
function DisableButtons<%=ClientID %>()
{
    var btnEdit = $('#<%= btnEdit.ClientID %>');
    var btnDelete = $('#<%= btnDelete.ClientID %>');
    var btnDetails = $('#<%= btnDetails.ClientID %>');
    btnEdit.addClass('disabled');
    btnEdit.attr('onClick','');
    btnDelete.addClass('disabled');
    btnDelete.attr('onClick','');
    btnDetails.addClass('disabled');
    btnDetails.attr('onClick','');
    <% for (int i = 0; i < AdditionalCommandsWithoutSeparator.Count(); i ++){ %>
         $('#<%= AdditionalCommandsWithoutSeparator[i].ButtonClientID %>').addClass('disabled');
         $('#<%= AdditionalCommandsWithoutSeparator[i].ButtonClientID %>').attr('onClick', '');
    <%} %>
}
```

The function AsserValidSelection is called on every pageload and goes fine most of the time. The moments it happens is when the index of a specific dropdown (RadComboBox) changes or when a specific button is pressed (the save button, cancel gives no issues). But the bug occurs before a breakpoint in code behind is triggered (which will never get triggered).

the error is :

> ArgumentNullException. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

The ClientID isn't null and the function DisableButtons with correct ID does exist.

I'm certainly unsure if this is enough information for any help, but feel very free to ask for more.

Comment: Perhaps changing the design would make your life easier? ie. not duplicating functions for each client.

Comment: But how would i seperate these functions ? if in the same page, the same function works when A but not when B, which depends on how which control is used ?